# Apache Flex SDK Mavenizer: build the converter

Tags: maven, apache-flex

I'm trying to comple the Apache Flex SDK mavenizer tool, I need this tool to convert the Apache Flex Sdks in package suitable for the Maven repository .
I downloaded the git repository from

https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/flex-utilities.git

I followed the instruction in the README.txt that are similar to the [Building the Mavenizer](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLEX/Apache+Flex+SDK+Mavenizer) tutorial: I clone the repository, I entered in the `mavenizer` directory and I lunched `mvn package`.
The maven script ran without errors but I couldn't find any jar in the man `target` directory. 
Each module were correctly built but not the main jar.
So I coulnd't execute the converter

```
java -jar [path-to-the-maveinzer-jar]/mavenizer.jar "[sdkhome]" "[fdktarget]"
```

Could someone help me? Has anyone run into the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm happy to share here the answer they gave me in the [apache flex users forum](http://apache-flex-users.2333346.n4.nabble.com/Apache-Flex-SDK-Mavenizer-build-the-converter-td9480.html).

Actually there was a problem!

> Ups sorry for that ... I didn't update that page for quite some time.
> The problem is that you checked out the old version. The new version
> is in the develop branch. As soon as the mavenizer is officially
> released, master will contain the updated version.
>
> I did write down a little more detailed howto under:
> https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLEX/Quick+Start+Guide:+Building+Apache+Flex+applications+using+Maven
> (I just re-checked and fixed one problem)

I Hope that it could be useful !